# SVN checkout like revert with multiple external repo

Tags: svn, revert, svn-checkout

I need some expert advice on this.
I have repo or project in which 4 more external svn repo is linked. 
Say, the current revision of main project is 2500. 
The external project's of current revisions are for Ex-A 2100, Ex-B 2360, Ex-C 2410, Ex-D 2480

I need to check out to the revision  2300 of main project. 
But when I check out the r.2300 of main project, all external project have their current revision checked in.

How can I revert the other repos A, B, C, D to a certain revision e.g. r.2250
It seems svn revert do not work. I need something like A, B, C, D are checked out at revision 2250.

My current solution is, I have checked out my main project in a folder "Proj-2300" at r.2300
Then I checked out all A, B, C, D seprately in a folder with corresponding revision e.g. A to 2250, B to 2270, C to 2260, D to 2280. Then copy those folder back in my "Proj-2300" folder.

But I think there should be an option something like revert to get a clean copy at revision xxxx. No merging. Just like checkout at revision xxxx.

Comment: It's a bad idea to use `svn:externals` without _explicit revision numbers_. Please read [Externals Definition](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html) and in particular the tip starting with "You should seriously consider using explicit revision numbers ..."

Comment: Surely I am working with something developed by my predecessors. I have to go with that until I restructure the whole system :(
However this is a great tips to me. Thanks anyway.